# Correct way to update array from setState - Typescript , ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am currently still new at typescript and i do not know if i am doing the things right . I want to update my array and i want to set an initial state as an empty array.
At the moment i am doing this :

```
 const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
```

And my update function is this :

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectValue((selectValue: any) => [{ ...selectValue, [e.target.value]: e.target.name }]);
  };
```

And the output is this :

```
0: {Ananas : "A"} , Banana : "B"
```

What am i doing wrong , because i want my output to be equal to one object like this :

```
0: {Ananas : "A" , Banana : "B"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have only one item inside the array that collect all the keys then you have to do something like this:

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
  setSelectValue((selectValue: any) => {
    const newSelectValue = [...selectValue]
    if (!newSelectValue[0]) newSelectValue[0] = {}

    return newSelectValue.map((value, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        return { ...value, [e.target.value]: e.target.name }
      } else {
        return value
      }
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: Btw, I believe you are mutating the state here `newSelectValue[0]`.  While `newSelectValue` refers to new array, `newSelectValue[0]` refers to state value (old array), which should be immutable by the default.

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes you're right. I updated the answer in order to get rid of that mutability. What do you think now? It's better?

Comment: Pls remove `const newSelectValue = [...selectValue]
    if (!newSelectValue[0]) newSelectValue[0] = {}`

Comment: Why? If the array is empty and we not init the first element in that way, when we map the array it will do nothing.